# Cómo resolver este problema para visualizar en modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal

Estoy trabajando con `datatable` y he agregado dos botones por columna para tema de visualización. El problema es que al visualizar por ejemplo `PDF1` me abre el modal pero a veces me muestra el `pdf` que contiene pero otras veces no. Al revisar en la consola se me ejecuta los dos script, y debería ejecutar solamente uno: al que hace mención con el botón `PDF1`. Si alguien me puede ayudar con ese. Saludos

```
  {"defaultContent": "<button type='button' id='a' class='btn btn-outline-success PDF1'  data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#PDF1'>DATOS1</button>"},
                 
  {"defaultContent": "<button type='button' id='b' class='btn btn-outline-info PDF2'  data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#PDF2'>DATOS2</button>"}


<!--MODAL PDF1---------------------------------------------------------------------->

<div class="modal fade" id="PDF1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">CARNET DE IDENTIDAD</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                   $(document).on('click', 'button[type="button"]', function(event) {
                    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
                    user_id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(1)').text());

                    console.log(user_id);
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'archivo_pdf1.php',
                        data: {valor_x: user_id},
                        success: function (data) {
                         $("#foto_pdf1").val(data.foto_pdf1);
                         var url="archivo_datos1/"+data.foto_pdf1;
                         $('#r').attr('src',url)
                     }
                 });
                });
               });
           </script>
           <div> 
              <embed src="" id="r"  width="100%" height="600px" type="application/pdf"></embed> 
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<!--MODAL PDF2---------------------------------------------------------------------->

<div class="modal fade" id="PDF2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">LICENCIA DE CONDUCIR</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function() {
                   $(document).on('click', 'button[type="button"]', function(event) {
                    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
                    user_id1 = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(1)').text());

                    console.log(user_id1);
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'archivo_pdf2.php',
                        data: {valor_x: user_id1},
                        success: function (data) {
                        $("#foto_pdf1").val(data.foto_pdf1);
                        var url="archivo_datos2/"+data.foto_pdf2;
                        $('#x').attr('src',url)
                     }
                 });
                });
               });
           </script>

           <div> 

              <embed src="" id="x"  width="100%" height="600px" type="application/pdf"></embed> 

          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu error esta en el evento onclick, deberias accionar el evento mediante el id del boton y no por el tipo, ya que tienes 2 botones o más ```$(document).on('click', 'button[type="button"]',```

Comment: @ernestojimenez tendría que cambiar 'button[type="button"]',

Comment: Si, el selector puede ser un id o una clase, pero que no se repitan un boton con el otro

Comment: @ernestojimenez gracias estimado. No me habia percatado de ese detalle. Saludos

Comment: Lo colocare como respuesta y espero tu calificacion gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta en que estas tratando de seleccionar un boton tipo button

`$(document).on('click', 'button[type="button"]'`

En el cual estas validando que hagan click en el, sin embargo, lo estas haciendo en ambas funciones, tanto para pdf1 como pdf2, ademas de que ambos botones poseen el mismo tipo, por lo tanto, no puedes realizar la seleccion mediante el tipo button ya que esto tratara de seleccionar o 1, o ninguno, o ambos y alli arrojara problemas.

Para solucionar esto primero debes identificar cada boton con un id unico o una clase unica

```
<button type="button" id='pdf1' class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
```

```
<button type="button" id='pdf2' class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
```

Seguido de esto cambiar la forma de seleccionar el boton para cada funcion

`$(document).on('click', '#pdf1',`

`$(document).on('click', '#pdf2',`